# Test suites in Azure DevOps

Tags: testing, azure-devops, testcase, test-suite, test-plan

Hi so I want to create multiple test suites in a test plan but I want them all under the same PBI and I can't tell if I just can't figure it out and there must be another way or if it's simply impossible. Your help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A test suite can not be under PBI. PBI can not include test suites. PBI includes only test cases. You can import PBI to Test Plan as a Requirement-based suite and then add test cases to it. Check the docs:

1. [Test objects and terms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/test-objects-overview?view=azure-devops)
2. [Add a requirement-based test suite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/create-a-test-plan?view=azure-devops#add-a-requirement-based-test-suite)

Comment: All right, I understand now. But if I still need to create multiple test suites?

Comment: @SadStudent you can not do that. 1 PBI in a backlog equals 1 Test suite in a Test plan. You may create a Static test suite named your PBI and create many child test suites. However, in this case, you will not see test results in the backlog and new bugs will not be linked to PBI during a test run.